# Restoring an old backup to the latest ios version returns an error

Tags: itunes, backup, ipod-touch, restore, ios

I am trying to restore an old backup of mine to my ipod, my backup is a year old. I wouldn't need to do this if apple didn't screw up my ipod during my 8.1 update where it just kept restarting and eventually didn't turn on anymore. What i did then is i restored my ipod clean. Now what i want to do is to recover as much of the files I can so i decided to use that year old backup, everything started fine i can find it in my PC it started restoring but in the middle it returned an error. Any ideas on why this is happening? my ipod is running the latest ios version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an iPod Touch. It went info DFU mode, and could not find the iTunes server, and was throwing up errors. It all began to work again once I shut down both the Mac and the iPod, restarting both. Some sort of I/O or USB issue I suppose. YMMV

Comment: were errors thrown during the restoration process as well?

Comment: Yes, in my case, restoration couldn't take place, because the iPod could not be found.